# How do I create a page-transition where the old page can't be reached via the back-button in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have an app with three pages: A, B and C. A is the startpage and has a button to open B via a `Navigator.push()`. Then B open C via `Navigator.push()`. Can I configure it in a way that pressing the back button in C brings me back to A and not C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pushReplacement` method, for example:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => PageC(),
  ),
);
```

This method:

- replace the current route (of the navigator by pushing the given route)

and

- disposing the previous route